# ConstraintLayout: Setting layout_constraintWidth_percent="1" breaks RecyclerView item layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

On a RecyclerView inside a ConstraintLayout, I'm trying to use `layout_constraintWidth_percent` to support 2 different layouts.  1 for phone, 1 for tablet.

For phone, we want the RecyclerView width to be 100%

We use `match_parent` on our list item width.

**TLDR**: The issue is that setting `layout_constraintWidth_percent` to `"1"` or `"1.0"` results in the RecyclerView item width not matching the parent, instead it wraps content.  However `"0.99"` or `"0.999"` work as expected!

Does anyone know if this is intended behavior for `layout_constraintWidth_percent` or is it a bug?

The [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.html) states to use "a value between 0 and 1", but I expected that 100% (or `1`) would be a typical use case.

**Details**

my_layout.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="@integer/recyclerview_width_percentage"
    app:spanCount="@integer/recycler_span_count" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:minHeight="48dp"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:paddingTop="8dp"
  android:paddingBottom="8dp">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:padding="2dp" />

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/header_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Value set to 0.999

Appears as intended with width matching parent

[image: Value set to 0.999]

#### Value set to 1

Breaks! Wraps content instead of matching parent

[image: Value set to 1]

Comment: is there any specific reason you need to use 100% width instead of omitting that parameter and letting the layout fit constraints?

Comment: In a tablet layout we are using another value, e.g 80% @Pawel

Comment: any update here? This also happen on Gridlayout manager and will not display any of the row item.

Comment: I came across with this one as well.